# rpc over https certificate error

Tags: exchange-2003, https, rpc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rpc over https certificate error](https://serverfault.com/questions/175646/rpc-over-https-certificate-error)

i'm trying to get rpc over https working.

the only thing i cant figure out is the certitificate
i have heard that i need a ucc or uuc certificate?

does somebody have a manual of tutorial how to create suchs a certificate

ws2k3 with exchange 2003.

greetz.

Comment: So what's the error referred to in your title?

Answer (score 0):

Depends, do you want an externally hosted certificate? (Free from here: https://www.startssl.com/?app=12)
How to use: http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/SSL-Enabling-OWA-2003-Using-Free-3rdParty-Certificate.html

Or an internally created one?

Free: http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/SSL_Enabling_OWA_2003.html

Once you have OWA using HTTPS, you can start using RPC over HTTPS.

(If you have turned it on in Exchange of course, your question seemed to be about the certificate)